# Add Training and Testing Accuracy to a Simple Neural Network in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I know this is a primitive question but what should I add in my code for it to output the training accuracy of the Neural Network in addition to the loss, I checked PyTorch tutorials and they show how to add training/testing accuracy in image classification but I do not know how to do that in my simple XOR solving NN, below is the code:

```
# Step 1: importing our dependencies
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np

# Our data
x = Variable(torch.Tensor([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], 
                           [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]))
y = Variable(torch.Tensor([[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0]]))

# Step 2: building our class model             
class NeuralNetwork(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.linear_ij = torch.nn.Linear(3, 4)
    self.linear_jk = torch.nn.Linear(4, 1)

def forward(self, x):
    matmul = self.linear_ij(x)
    activation = torch.sigmoid(matmul)
    matmul = self.linear_jk(activation)
    prediction = torch.sigmoid(matmul)
    return prediction

# Our model
model = NeuralNetwork()

# Constructing the loss function and the optimization algorithm
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss(reduction='mean')
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1)

# Step 3: the training process
for epoch in range(10000):

    prediction = model(x)
    loss = criterion(prediction, y)

    if epoch % 1000 == 0 or epoch == 10000 - 1:
        print("epoch ", epoch, ",", "loss: ", loss.item())

    # Backpropagation process
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

and this is it what it gives as an output:

```
epoch  0 , loss:  0.6983293294906616
epoch  1000 , loss:  0.015215665102005005
epoch  2000 , loss:  0.0048239342868328094
epoch  3000 , loss:  0.00280318153090775
epoch  4000 , loss:  0.001963752554729581
epoch  5000 , loss:  0.0015071843517944217
epoch  6000 , loss:  0.0012211233843117952
epoch  7000 , loss:  0.0010254186345264316
epoch  8000 , loss:  0.000883264874573797
epoch  9000 , loss:  0.0007753585232421756
epoch  9999 , loss:  0.0006908221403136849
```

As for testing:

```
# Testing our model
model.eval()

x_test = Variable(torch.Tensor([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]))
y_test = Variable(torch.Tensor([[0], [0], [1]]))
y_pred = model(x_test)
print(model(x_test))
```

with the output:

```
tensor([[0.0026],
        [0.0011],
        [0.9991]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add accuracy you only need one line, namely:

```
print("Accuracy: ", ((prediction > 0.5) == y).float().mean().item())
```

When you use `sigmoid` anything greater than `0.5` is considered positive and anything below negative. `(prediction > 0.5)` creates a `tensor` of `bool` type and you check which of those are equal to `y`. `float()` is needed as you cannot calculate `mean` of `bool` tensors. `item()` isn't needed but returns python value from single valued `tensor` and IMO looks cleaner this way.

You can do the same for `test`, hence it would be:

```
model.eval()

x_test = Variable(torch.Tensor([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]))
y_test = Variable(torch.Tensor([[0], [0], [1]]))
with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = model(x_test)
    print("Accuracy: ", ((y_pred > 0.5) == y_test).float().mean().item())
```

Please notice `torch.no_grad()`. This context manager disables `autograph` when you are within it's scope. As you are just passing inputs through your neural network and not training it using gradients there is no need for autograph to be a part of the equation.

### Working with logits

It's usually a good habit **not to use final activation** in your neural networks (unless you really need it). Hence your forward would look like this:

```
def forward(self, x):
    matmul = self.linear_ij(x)
    activation = torch.sigmoid(matmul)
    # Notice no sigmoid
    return self.linear_jk(activation)
```

This outputs `logits` (let's say unnormalized probability ranging from `[-inf, inf]`) indicating how confident your neural network is it's positive (`+inf`) or negative class.

You have to change your loss function accordingly, e.g. `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` (`mean` is deafult reduction, no need to make it explicit here):

```
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

Finally, accuracy changes slightly as well. Now anything greater than `0` is considered positive, hence you would do this:

```
print("Accuracy: ", ((prediction > 0) == y).float().mean().item())
```

If you need probability you can use `torch.sigmoid` on the output still, but you might not even need it (as it seems in this case).

### EDIT

You should also specify your data as `torch.Tensor`, `torch.Variable` is deprecated (`tensors` already have `requires_grad=True`), e.g.:

```
x = torch.Tensor(
    [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
)
y = torch.Tensor([[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0]])
```

### EDIT2:

It should be placed below (or above) your loss printing, e.g.:

```
for epoch in range(10000):

    prediction = model(x)
    loss = criterion(prediction, y)

    if epoch % 1000 == 0 or epoch == 10000 - 1:
        # Here is fine
        print("Accuracy: ", ((prediction > 0.5) == y).float().mean().item())
        print("epoch ", epoch, ",", "loss: ", loss.item())

    # Backpropagation process
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error: "Expected object of scalar type Byte but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'other'"

Comment: What's your pytorch version? It's perfectly fine on `1.4.0`. Added an edit as well

Comment: Thank you my PyTorch version is 1.0.1 which explains the error. I wanted to upvote your answer but I need 15 reputations. Thank you so much for the detailed answer, really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, now you have enough to upvote, happy StackOverflowing and keep your dependencies quite up to date. :)

Comment: Hi @SzymonMaszke, last question if you don't mind: 
Where should the print accuracy line be situated in the training loop? Should it be like this: 
if epoch % 1000 == 0 or epoch == 10000 - 1: 
    print("epoch ", epoch, ",", "loss: ", loss.item()) 
    print("Accuracy: ", ((prediction > 0.5) == y).float().mean().item()) 
and can it be written like this: 
print("epoch ", epoch, ",", "loss: ", loss.item(), "Accuracy: ", ((prediction > 0.5) == y).float().mean().item())

Comment: Edited my answer